# How can I create a Pie Chart with rounded slice edges?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, core-graphics, pie-chart

I want to achieve the following effect, shown below in my iOS app (written in Swift)

[image: piechart-image]

So far I have been able to achieve this, using [Charts by danielgindi](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). But I am not able to get the desired effect as I want to. Is there any way to add rounded corners to each Pie Chart slice like in this example image here?:

[image: myimplementation]

My Chart setup is as follows:

```
let data1 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 3)
let data2 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 5)
let data3 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 4)
let data4 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 6)
let data5 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 8)
let values = [data1, data2, data3, data4, data5]
let chartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(entries: values, label: nil)
let chartData = PieChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
let colors = [UIColor.fuelTintColor, UIColor.maintenanceTintColor, UIColor.insuranceTintColor, UIColor.fastagTintColor, UIColor.miscTintColor]
chartDataSet.colors = colors as! [NSUIColor]
chartDataSet.sliceSpace = 10
        
pieChart1.data = chartData
        
pieChart1.holeRadiusPercent = 0.8
```

I think it can be done using the `PieChartRenderer` but I have no idea how I should proceed.

Also, if you have any suggestions for other ways to implement this do let me know.

Comment: Try this : https://github.com/AAChartModel/AAChartKit-Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, and here's the output:

[ring-chart-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfdsO.jpg)

Basically I am using this library, called CircularProgressView (https://cocoapods.org/pods/CircleProgressView) to achieve the individual rings. Since I needed 5 rings, I stacked 5 such views (with clear background) on top of each other and rotated them to achieve my desired effect.

#### Cocoapod setup

First, you have to install the CircularProgressView pod in your project. I am using Cocoapods for importing the library here.

**NOTE:** If you do not have Cocoapods setup already then you need to install Cocoapods first using steps here: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

To add it using Cocoapods, add the following line in your Podfile.

```
pod 'CircleProgressView'
```

and run `pod install` on the Terminal from within your project directory.

#### Interface Builder

In your Storyboard file, go to your View Controller and add a view and set its contents. You can also create this view programmatically but here I will be using the storyboard.

Create 4 more views and use Auto Layout to stack them on top of one another.

Select all 5 views and go to the Identity Inspector (right panel in storyboard, 4th item in top bar).

Set the `Class` field value (under Custom Class) as 'CircularProgressView'.

Link all 5 views to your `ViewController.swift` file.

I have named them as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pieChart1: CircleProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var pieChart2: CircleProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var pieChart3: CircleProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var pieChart4: CircleProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var pieChart5: CircleProgressView!
```

Call the function `showRingChart()` in `viewDidLoad()` to setup the views.

Here is the code for the functions:

```
// Function to convert degrees to radian
func degToRad(_ rotationDegrees: Double) -> CGFloat {
    let rotationAngle = CGFloat(rotationDegrees * .pi/180.0)
    return rotationAngle
}

// Function to Show Ring Chart
func showRingChart() {
    
    // Values for the graph, can be changed as per your need
    let val1 = self.val1
    let val2 = self.val2
    let val3 = self.val3
    let val4 = self.val4
    let val5 = self.val5
    let totalVal = (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5)
    var spacing = 0.05 * totalVal // Spacing is set to 5% (ie. 0.05). Change it according to your needs
    
    print("Spacing: ", spacing)
    let totalSpacing = 5 * spacing //Total spacing value to be added in the chart
    
    let total = totalVal + totalSpacing //Total corresponding to 100% on the chart
    
    if val1 == 0.0
        && val2 == 0.0
        && val3 == 0.0
        && val4 == 0.0
        && val5 == 0.0 {
        
        // NO DATA, HIDE ALL CHARTS
        pieChart1.isHidden = true
        pieChart2.isHidden = true
        pieChart3.isHidden = true
        pieChart4.isHidden = true
        pieChart5.isHidden = true
        
    } else {

        // DATA AVAILABLE

        // Calculate Percentage of each value in the ring chart (ie. progress)
        let valOnePerc = (val1 / total) 
        let valTwoPerc = (val2 / total)
        let valThreePerc = (val3 / total)
        let valFourPerc = (val4 / total)
        let valFivePerc = (val5 / total)

        let spacingPerc = spacing / total
        
        // Angle offsets (in degrees)
        let offset1 = (valOnePerc + spacingPerc) * 360
        let offset2 = (valOnePerc + valTwoPerc + (2 * spacingPerc)) * 360
        let offset3 = (valOnePerc + valTwoPerc + valThreePerc + (3 * spacingPerc)) * 360
        let offset4 = (valOnePerc + valTwoPerc + valThreePerc + valFourPerc + (4 * spacingPerc)) * 360

        print("--- PRINTING CHART VALUES HERE ---- ")
        print(total)
        print(valOnePerc)
        print(valTwoPerc)
        print(valThreePerc)
        print(valFourPerc)
        print(valFivePerc)
        print(offset1)
        print(offset2)
        print(offset3)
        print(offset4)
        print("------------------")
        
        // Setup ring chart sections
        pieChart1.trackFillColor = UIColor.tintColorOne
        pieChart1.progress = valOnePerc
        
        pieChart2.trackFillColor = UIColor.tintColorTwo
        pieChart2.progress = valTwoPerc
        pieChart2.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degToRad(offset1))

        pieChart3.trackFillColor = UIColor.tintColorThree
        pieChart3.progress = valThreePerc
        pieChart3.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degToRad(offset2))

        pieChart4.trackFillColor = UIColor.tintColorFour
        pieChart4.progress = valFourPerc
        pieChart4.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degToRad(offset3))

        pieChart5.trackFillColor = UIColor.tintColorFive
        pieChart5.progress = valFivePerc
        pieChart5.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degToRad(offset4))
        
        // Unhide all charts
        pieChart1.isHidden = false
        pieChart2.isHidden = false
        pieChart3.isHidden = false
        pieChart4.isHidden = false
        pieChart5.isHidden = false

    }
}
```

It should do it. Change the (val1, val2, ..., val5) values to change the progress of the rings.